# How to call a javascript function with a browser in Java?

Tags: java, javascript

I have implemented a simple browser in java which load a html page(I wrote it), I want to call my javascript function, in my java my class!
I try the following code, but it didn't execute the script!

```
browser.execute("<script type='text/javascript'> "
                    +"loadMap("+lat+","+lng+");"
                    +"  </script>");
```

Comment: What's the class of `browser`?

Comment: it is browser : http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html

Comment: This is just for putting the script tag up on html document, you should probably put an additional code to invoke the loadMap function in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
browser.execute("loadMap("+lat+","+lng+");");
```

You don't need to create a `script` tag to execute the script. Just execute the actual JavaScript code. Refer to this [sample](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/).